# Combine multiple AutoCorrect files?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

I have a computer and a laptop and use Microsoft Word on each of these. On each, I have added a large number of words to my AutoCorrect list as I type quite fast and can often misspell words, so I find it easier to add each word I misspell to my AutoCorrect list so that it corrects it for me.

However, I would like to now combine both of my lists as they differ from each other as I have typed different content on each device. My understanding is that I can go to *%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Office* and move the .acl files to the other computer.

I am however wondering if there is a way to merge both of these together. Thank you for any ideas you may have on how to do this.

Comment: Use Jay Freedman's AutoCorrect2007 utility on each computer. http://jay-freedman.info/ It creates a Word file with your AutoCorrect entries in a table. You can combine the two tables and then use the Restore feature. This is likely the best  answer you will find, but for SE it does not count as an answer because it just refers you elsewhere. Greg Maxey has a similar utility - creates a Word document that can be edited. http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/autocorrect_utility_manager.html Also an AutoCorrect Generator: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/autocorrect_generator.html

Comment: Perfect - thank you very much!